# what do cocycles look like

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Assume a finite simplicial complex with a chain group defined on the basis of simplices.

a cocycle $\bar{c}$ is defined as a cochain s.t. $\delta(\bar{c})$ = 0 where $\delta$ is the transpose of the boundary matrix $\partial$

cycles are defined as chains c s.t. $\partial(c)$= 0.

cycles have a nice geometric interpretation in simplicial homology: in 1 dimension the boundary of a polygon forms a cycle.

what about cocycles? do they have a nice geometric interpretation? (just a special case would be enough)

Comment: See page 186 [in Allen Hatcher's book](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf), "The idea of cohomology."

Comment: You can think of them as functions on the chains to a field, with the added condition that they behave in a "nice" way on the lower dimensional chains.